# text field character limit based on number field in same form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, ajaxform

I am not sure if this is possible but what I am trying to accomplish is a text field which would have a character limit of 5 characters if a number field in the same form has 5 entered, or whatever number is entered as the limit.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: set a counter , if entered character exceed counter disable text filed or hide entering

Comment: <input type="text" maxlength="5">

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that
you just need to set maxlength attribute on basis of numeric textbox

```js
$("#txtNumber").keyup(function(){
    $("#txtBox").attr("maxlength",$(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="txtNumber">
<input type="text" id="txtBox">
```